# Using xpath to extract only the text being part of the parent node

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

How can we only select and extract text which is only part of the parent node. Here is the HTML i am working on. I need to extract only the "$1950" using the xpath. When i select the parent node and extract its text content i get the the text content of its childs as well, but i need the text content of parent node only.

```
<span class="rentRollup">

 <span class="longText">3 Bedrooms</span>
 <span class="shortText">3 Beds</span>
 $1,950

</span>
```

I have tried using the xpath but its printing the whole parent node as well as the child nodes data.

```
url = 'https://www.apartments.com/214-taylor-st-raleigh-nc/cr6tchd/'
#intializing request headers
ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print(response)
byte_data = response.content 
source_code = html.fromstring(byte_data)
name=source_code.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '3 Bedrooms')]/..")
name=name[0].text_content()
print(name)
```

Comment: Is the structure of the html code always such that your target string (`$1950` in this case) is inside a `span` tag which has two `span` children?

Comment: yes always the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way: after `print(response)`, replace everything with:

```
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
name=tree.xpath("//span[@class='rentRollup']/text()")
name[2].strip()
```

Output:

> '$1,950'

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath expression

```
//*[contains(*/text(), '3 Bedrooms')]/text()
```

will select just the text nodes which are direct children of the parent node of interest. But there is still whitespace-noise which you need to get rid of.